# Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa linguagem formal?

Tags: teoria-da-computação

Alguém poderia me ajudar com a seguinte linguagem:

```
{a^n b^m | n<= m <= 2n}
```

Desculpe a ignorância, mas não estou conseguindo formar um autômato de pilha com essa linguagem. Estou tentando através de um autômato determinístico de pilha mas não sai nada.

Comment: De qual linguagem estamos falando?

Comment: linguagem formal

Answer (score 7):

`{a^n b^m | n<= m <= 2n}` quer dizer:

> Aceita-se expressão com N elementos e A e M elementos de B, sendo M entre N e 2N.

Na prática, o autômato aceita:

```
AB
ABB
AABB
AABBB
AABBBB
...
```

Ou seja, a quantidade de `B` precisa ser igual à quantidade de `A`, ou maior que a quantidade de `A`, desde que não seja maior que o dobro de `A`.

---

**EDIT**

[Achei esse site bacana](http://automatonsimulator.com/) pra te ajudar.

Comment: entendi, agora só tenho que criar um automato de pilha pra isso e é isso que não estou conseguindo, obrigado cara!

Comment: [Não esqueça de passear pelo Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). De nada!

Answer (score 3):

A seguinte gramática é o suficiente para reconhecer essa linguagem:

[image: Gramática que obriga n <= m <= 2n]

Essa gramática gera palavras incrementalmente, aumentando sempre um `a` e um ou dois `b`s de modo auto-aninhado.

Essa gramática é uma [gramática livre de contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/64969), gerada a partir dessa meta-linguagem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215974/64969

O autômato de pilha é esse:

[image: autômato de pilha]

Eu criei uma questão auto-respondida para tratar justamente da transformação de gramáticas livres de contexto para autômatos de pilha. Inclusive, usei a gramática desta questão como exemplo