# Como transformar uma gramática livre de contexto em um autômato de pilha?

Tags: algoritmo, teoria-da-computação, autômatos, linguagens-formais

Eu tenho uma gramática, como por exemplo:

[image: gramática que obriga a quantidade de b's ser entre [1,2] vezes a quantidade de a's]

Ou então:

[image: gramática regular, portanto também livre de contexto]

Ou mesmo essa:

[image: outra gramática regular da qual eu me lembrei]

Ou então essa gramática, que representa a lógica booleana para três variáveis:

[image: gramática para operações booleanas]

- Como transformar essas gramáticas em autômatos de pilha?
- Teria alguma relação entre estados e não terminais?
- Poderia mostrar a execução desse algoritmo para as gramáticas dadas como exemplo?

> Relacionadas:
>
> - [O que é uma linguagem livre de contexto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/64969)
> - [Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa linguagem formal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208540/64969)
> - [O que é uma meta linguagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215963/64969)
> - [Expressão regular para reconhecer linguagem: palavras que não contenham "bbab"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe sim um algoritmo que permita fazer exatamente isso, transformar uma gramática qualquer em um autômato de pilha não determinístico. A ideia é que toda produção gramatical consuma, no máximo, um elemento da palavra de entrada. Para tal, toda produção deve conter terminal apenas no começo, se contiver algum terminal, e apenas na quantia de um.

Por exemplo, algumas das produções que satisfazem essa condição são:

- `S -> b B1`
- `O -> A B_op A`
- `S -> lambda`

Exemplos de produções que não satisfazem:

- `S -> aSb`
- `S -> aSbb`
- `A -> ( O )`

pois contém terminais à direita.

Para esses casos, criamos um novo não terminal equivalente ao terminal em questão. Por exemplo:

- `S -> aSb`, usando `B` para o não terminal equivalente a `b`:

  - `S -> aSB`
- `S -> aSbb`, usando `B` para o não terminal equivalente a `b`:

  - `S -> aSBB`
- `A -> ( O )`, usando `F` para o não terminal equivalente a `)`:

  - `A -> ( O F`

Após rodar esse processo, as seguintes gramáticas novas foram produzidas:

> Nota: elas são equivalentes às anteriores; só mostro aqui as gramáticas que tiveram produções novas criadas de acordo com o algoritmo acima descrito.

[image: quantidades de b's entre 1 e 2 vezes a de a, contanto que todos os a's estejam aglutinados à esquerda]

E também:

[image: mais outra gramática livre de contexto]

E também

[image: gramática normalizada para operações lógicas]

## Criando o autômato de pilha

O primeiro passo para se criar o autômato de pilha é colocar o não terminal inicial no começo da pilha. Isso é feito aplicando-se o seguinte esqueleto:

[image: esqueleto autômato de pilha]

Note que, aqui, a transição contém 3 elementos, um antes da vírgula e dois depois da vírgula, separados por uma barra.

Nesse caso, o valor antes da vírgula indica o que está sendo consumido da palavra de entrada. Como está `-` do esqueleto, isso significa que nesse momento não está sendo usado nenhum caracter da palavra de entrada.

Os dois próximos elementos depois da vírgula são `-/S`. No caso, isso quer dizer que, não consultando a cabeça da pilha (indicado pelo `-`), vai ser inserido o não terminal `S` na pilha. Note que, do lado esquerdo da barra só pode existir um único elemento, correspondente ao topo da pilha, porém podem existir diversos elementos do lado direito.

As próximas transações inseridas todas nascem do estado `ap` e desaguam no estado `ap` do esqueleto do autômato acima descrito. Note que, nesse caso, havendo transições do tipo `-,-/-` indo e voltando de outro estado `x` qualquer, `ap` e `x` são equivalentes. A transação `-,-/-` não consome nada da palavra de entrada, não consulta nem altera a pilha.

Note que só é possível cair nesse algoritmo de transformação em autômato de pilha após a transformação dos terminais não iniciais das regras de produção em não terminais equivalentes.

A palavra só é aceita, nesse caso, quando todos os caracteres da palavra de entrada foram consumidos e com pilha vazia.

### Produções que consomem elementos da pilha e da palavra de entrada

Vamos ver o caso de `S -> b B1`. Para transformar em transição do autômato, deverá ser consumida a letra `b` da entrada, `S` do topo da pilha e deve ser inserido `B1` na pilha. Portanto, a produção deveria ser `b,S/B1`.

### Produções que consomem elementos da pilha, mas não da palavra de entrada

Vamos estudar dois casos para esse aqui:

- `S -> lambda`
- `O -> A B_op A`

Para o case `S -> lambda`, a transformação simplesmente consome `S` do topo da pilha. Portanto, ela é `-,S/-`.

Para `O -> A B_op A`, consumimos `O` e colocamos na pilha `A B_Op A`. Portanto, a transação é `-,O/A B_op A`.

### Primeira gramática transformada em autômato de pilha

A primeira gramática já sofreu normalização. Foi aplicado o algoritmo de normalização e obtida:

[image: quantidades de b's entre 1 e 2 vezes a de a, contanto que todos os a's estejam aglutinados à esquerda]

Com isso, temos as seguintes transições de `ap` para `ap`:

- `a,S/S B`
- `a,S/S B B`
- `b,B/-`
- `-,S/-`

Por questão de legibilidade, criei um estado `a1` equivalente a `ap`:

[image: autômato de pilha]

### Segunda gramática transformada em autômato de pilha

A segunda gramática foi normalizada para essa forma aqui:

[image: mais outra gramática livre de contexto]

Portanto, suas transições são:

- `-,S/Nb S`
- `b,S/B1`
- `b,B1/B2`
- `b,B2/B2`
- `a,B2/A`
- `-,B1/Nb S`
- `-,B2/Nab S`
- `-,A/Nb S`
- `a,Nb/-`
- `c,Nb/-`
- `d,Nb/-`
- `c,Nab/-`
- `d,Nab/-`

> Mais tarde colocarei o autômato aqui

### Terceira gramática transformada em autômato de pilha

Essa gramática não precisou de nenhuma transformação, já estava normalizada o suficiente.

> Mais tarde colocarei as transações e o autômato aqui

### Quarta gramática transformada em autômato de pilha

Essa gramática precisou normalizar apenas a questão do fecha parênteses, ficando assim:

[image: gramática normalizada para operações lógicas]

Suas transações são (considerando estado inicial `O`):

- `-,O/A`
- `(,A/O F`
- `),F/-`
- `-,O/A Bo A`
- `-,O/Uo A`
- `a,A/-`
- `b,A/-`
- `c,A/-`
- `¬,Uo/-`
- `^,Bo/-`
- `v,Bo/-`
- `=>,Bo/-`
- `<=>,Bo/-`

O seguinte autômato de pilha reconhece essa linguagem:

[image: autômato de pilha que reconhece expressões em álgebra booleana de até 3 variáveis]