# Reduzir gramáticas na hierarquia de Chomsky

Tags: ciência-da-computação, teoria-da-computação, linguagens-formais

Sei que pela hierarquia de Chomsky, toda **gramática regular** é também uma **gramática livre de contexto**. Analogamente, sei que uma **gramática livre de contexto** também é uma **gramática sensível ao contexto** e etc.

Gostaria de saber como **provar** que o *contrário* não se aplica, isto é, *que pode ou não existir* uma **gramática livre de contexto** que seja **regular**. Ou seja, que isso é indecidível.

Comment: Fiquei um pouco confuso. Você quer provar que nem toda linguagem livre de contexto é regular?

Comment: @LINQ exatamente. Mas eu também queria saber se eu posso dizer o mesmo para as linguagens em outros níveis da hierarquia. Vou tentar ser mais claro: além de provar que nem toda linguagem livre de contexto é regular eu também quero provar que nem toda sensível ao contexto é livre de contexto.

Comment: A minha intenção nessa pergunta é saber se eu posso ou não sempre ter uma gramática equivalente mas num nível reduzido na hierarquia de chomsky. Eu quero provar que isso é indecidível.

Comment: Existem casos decidíveis em que a resposta é um tácito não. Você quer um caso indecidível ou um não pra valer?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado aguardando a resposta :)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não sei se entendi a sua pergunta. Quer dizer se eu quero um exemplo de casos decidíveis ou indecidíveis? A minha dúvida é em provar que linguagem pode ou não ser reduzida. Acho que não estou conseguindo ser claro.

Comment: Acima eu quis dizer "que **gramática** pode ou não ser reduzida".

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva obrigado pela ênfase, eu havia lido **linguagem**. Ok, gramática realmente é indecidível. Estou trabalhando na resposta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu já agradeço desde já o teu empenho. Assim como Maniero estou no aguardo :-)

Comment: E eu também (só pra colocar uma pressãozinha :p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na Hierarquia de Chomsky, temos as seguintes gramáticas, da mais simples à mais poderosa:

1. Gramática regular
2. Gramática livre de contexto
3. Gramática sensível a contexto
4. Gramática irrestrita

> **Curiosidade**: essa não é a nomenclatura de Chomsky. Ele chama de **gramática de Markov** (ou coisa semelhante) o que os matemáticos e cientistas/teóricos da computação chamam de **gramática regular**, e também chama de **gramática regular** o que os matemáticos e cientistas/teóricos da computação chamam de **gramática livre de contexto**. Não lembro como chama a **sensível a contexto**, mas a **irrestrita** mantém a nomenclatura, na minha lembrança.

Uma gramática regular pode ser regular a direita ou regular a esquerda, dependendo de como são suas regras de derivação.

Regular a direita tem os seguintes formatos para regras de derivação (maiúsculas indicam não-terminais, minúsculas indicam terminais; `S` é o não-terminal inicial):

```
S ==> 
A ==> aB
A ==> a
```

Note que a palavra cresce da esquerda para a direita.

Regular a esquerda tem os seguintes formatos para regras de derivação:

```
S ==>
A ==> Ba
A ==> a
```

Já gramáticas livres de contexto tem apenas derivações livres de contexto: um não-terminal gerando uma forma léxica qualquer. Uma forma léxica é uma mistura de terminais e não-terminais, em qualquer ordem e qualquer quantidade (até mesmo λ é considerado uma forma léxica). Daí, fica fácil ver que toda produção regular é, também, livre de contexto.

> Para alguns jargões da área de linguagens formais, veja [essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210716/64969)

Uma forma (preguiçosa) de definir uma linguagem como regular é: aquela linguagem que pode ser representada por uma gramática regular. De modo análogo: a linguagem **X** é aquela que pode ser representada por uma gramática **X**.

Eu posso dizer que uma linguagem é *estritamente* livre de contexto se ela não puder ser representada por uma gramática mais simples do que a gramática livre de contexto. E isso vale para todas as outras linguagens.

Tomemos a linguagem `L = {a^n b^m |- n inteiro, m inteiro}`. Ela é livre de contexto? A resposta é: sim. Prova disso?

```
S ==>
S ==> A
S ==> B
S ==> AB
A ==> a
A ==> AA
B ==> b
B ==> BB
```

Agora, ela é *estritamente* livre de contexto? A resposta é: não.

> Estou me valendo do fato de que [expressões regulares são equivalentes a gramáticas regulares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242621/64969), pelo menos expressões regulares "puras", no conceito matemático

Prova disso: `a*b*`.

E a linguagem `L = {a^n b^m |- n inteiro, m inteiro, n <= m <= 2n }`? Seria ela livre de contexto?

[Sim, livre de contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208540/64969). E, se quiser o autômato dela, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243105/64969).

Agora, seria ela *estritamente* livre de contexto? Será que eu teria de pesquisar por todas as gramáticas regulares sobre os terminais `a` e `b` para analisar isso?

Felizmente, não precisamos fazer uma prova por esgotamento de opções. Elas são infinitamente enumeráveis, mas mesmo assim infinitas, não ia ser possível fazer esse tipo de demonstração em um tempo finito. Então, vamos acochar a matemática e os cintos de segurança?

Logo no começo do texto, eu coloquei como curiosidade que Chomsky chamava esse tipo de gramática como sendo uma *gramática de Markov*. Sabe por quê? Porque ele, inadvertidamente, usou um processo de Markov para criar um [autômato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260964/64969) gerador de palavras, ele criou uma [máquina de Mealy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine): para cada transação disparada na cadeia de Markov, um novo símbolo terminal era produzido.

> Eu flerto um pouco mais com autômatos generativos e cadeias de Markov [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240086/64969).

Então, como um autômato de estados finitos reconhece uma linguagem regular e, também, é uma espécie de cadeia de Markov, temos então que linguagens regulares são intimamente relacionadas com cadeias de Markov.

Se a minha cadeia de Markov permitir laços, e eu esteja em um de seus estados que pertencem ao laço, nada impede que eu faça esse laço infinitas vezes. Afinal, cadeias de Markov só são dependentes do estado atual na hora de determinar o próximo estado.

Para chegar no ponto em que ocorre o laço, talvez eu precise gerar na máquina de Mealy a subpalavra `x`. O laço completo me geraria a subpalavra `y`. Daí eu posso finalizar como a subpalavra `z`. Isso implica que as seguintes concatenações de palavras sejam reconhecidas exatamente pelo mesmo autômato:

```
xz
xyz
xyyz
xyyyyyyyyyyyyyyz
```

Ficar repetindo o laço que gera `y` é chamado de "bombeamento". Posso bombear `y`s a vontade que a palavra obtida continua pertencente à linguagem. Então, segue o [lema do bombeamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) para linguagens regulares: se não existir `x`, `y` e `z` que satisfazem essa condição, então a linguagem não é regular.

No caso, nossa gramática é livre de contexto, se ela for não-regular, então não há gramática mais simples que represente essa linguagem, portanto ela seria estritamente livre de contexto.

Tomemos a palavra arbitrária `a^n b^m` que pertença à linguagem, para algum `n` e algum `m` válidos. Posso pegar a subpalavra `y` de uma das seguintes formas:

- *puro-a*: só contenha `a`
- *puro-b*: só contenha `b`
- *misto*: começa com alguns `a`s, depois seguem alguns `b`s

Qualquer que seja o `y` misto, bombear o segundo `y` já torna a nova palavra inválida. Veja: `a^n b a b^m`; bombeei `ab` mais uma única vez. Isso não respeitou à definição da linguagem de que todos os `a`s são do lado esquerdo, e que todos os `b`s são do lado direito.

Para *puro-a*, o que acontece se eu bombear `m` vezes a mais? O meu menor resultado seria `a^(n+m) b^m`. Como a quantidade de `a`s é maior do que a quantidade de `b`s, essa palavra obtida também não pertence a linguagem.

Então, será que a alternativa *puro-b* consegue mostrar algo de regular? Bem, a resposta é não. Bombeie `2n` vezes, então a menor palavra seria `a^n b^(m+2n)`. A quantidade de `b`s se tornou estritamente maior do que o dobro da quantidade de `a`, também desqualificando essa palavra como pertencente à linguagem.

Então, como não há alternativas mais sobrando para provar que é gerada por una cadeia de Markov, então posso afirmar que, por esgotamento, não é gerada por uma cadeia de Markov; isso implica que não há autômato finito que reconheça; e isso implica a inexistência de gramática regular para reconhecer essa linguagem.

Portanto, `L = { a^n b^m |- n inteiro, m inteiro, n <= m <= 2n }` é estritamente livre de contexto.

---

Sobre a possibilidade de determinar, genericamente, que uma gramática livre de contexto `G`, que gera a linguagem `L(G)`, não pode ser simplificado para uma gramática regular `R` tal que `L(G) = L(R)`... bem, em alguns casos você consegue decidir entre *sim* ou *não*, mas no caso geral isso não é possível.

Você encontrará alguns casos em que [não é possível parar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/64969) com uma resposta para a pergunta. Desconheço a demonstração dessa propriedade, mas conheço muito bem esse resultado da impossibilidade de determinar se uma gramática livre de contexto não é um expressão regular disfarçada.

Comment: Alguém traga um prêmio pra este homem! Jefferson, me ajudou demais! você é o cara e só tenho a agradecer.