# O que é o Pumping Lemma (ou Lema do Bombeamento) ? E como aplicá-lo?

Tags: teoria-da-computação, autômatos, linguagens-formais

Estava lendo pelo HOPCROFT e tive dificuldade em aplicar o lema do bombeamento de maneira formal aos exercícios para provar que uma linguagem não é regular.

Neste caso, me refiro ao Lema do Bombeamento para linguagens regulares.

Em alguns casos consegui mostrar casos específicos, mas minha professora somente aceita provas generalistas na avaliação.

Comment: Ótima questão, mas estou meio sem cabeça pra responder. Dei exemplos em outras perguntas da tag [tag:linguagens-formais], deve ter um conhecimento espalhado por aí. Um desses exemplos foi recente, está [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313192/64969). No caso, voltado a linguagens regulares. Mas deve ter em algum lugar um lema do bombeamento para LLC em alguma resposta solta. Não conheço lema do bombeamento para linguagens sensíveis a contexto, também acho que não haja para gramáticas irrestritas (só lembrando, gramáticas irrestritas são Turing-completas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### O que é o lema do bombeamento

O lema do bombeamento é uma condição *sine qua non* de linguagens regulares/livres de contexto (dependendo de qual você esteja usando, claro). Porém, não é uma condição *suficiente*.

> Como você pediu para focar apenas no lema do bombeamento para linguagens regulares, fica esta nota aqui dizendo que existe o lema do bombeamento para linguagens livres de contexto.

Isso significa que, para toda linguagem regular, é possível "bombear mais vezes" uma string. Dou mais exemplos sobre isso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358113/64969).

Qual o pensamento atrás do lema do bombeamento? Bem, que temos um processo de Markov rodando (esse processo é, como implicado por Chomsky em [seu artigo](https://chomsky.info/wp-content/uploads/195609-.pdf), o autômato finito da linguagem regular) que gera/identifica palavras em uma linguagem regular. Então, isso significa que há uma rota entre o começo da palavra até o seu final. Se, por acaso, essa rota fizer um laço, eu poderia repeti-lo infinitas vezes e ainda assim seria algo válido no processo de Markov. Então, já que se trata de um processo de Markov, posso repetir o laço que a nova palavra gerada por essa nova rota estará na linguagem regular.

> O [artigo do Chomsky](https://chomsky.info/wp-content/uploads/195609-.pdf) é de uma leitura muito boa e divertida, afinal, "incolores ideias verdes dormem furiosamente". Só que ele parece que foi escaneado e a fonte do PDF não ficou lá muito agradável de ler. Melhor ler impresso.
>
> Leia também [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313192/64969), tem até mesmo um quadrado de curiosidade para tentar auxiliar a não se perder entre os termos de Chomsky e os termos dos cientistas da computação/matemáticos. Imagina, Chomsky usa um termo que existe para os matemáticos, porém com um significado totalmente distinto...

Tá, tem algum exemplo desse laço e do processo de Markov? Peguemos [esse autômato finito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969):

[image: autômato que reconhece todas as palavras em <code>{a,b}*</code> que não contenham a subpalavra <code>bbab</code>]

Vamos supor que eu segui o seguinte caminho (ou supor que reconheci a palavra `bbba`):

```
q0 -> qb1 -> qb2 -> qb2 -> qa
```

Note que a aresta `qb2 -> qb2` forma uma subrota que é um laço sobre `qb2`. O laço mais simples possível, mas é um laço: inicia em um vértice e pára sobre ele mesmo. Nesse laço, produzimos exatamente o terceiro `b` da palavra `bbba`. Isso significa que podemos percorrer esse laço quantas vezes for que a palavra nova pertencerá à mesma linguagem. Ou seja, `bbbbbba` também é uma palavra válida.

No lema do bombeamento, esse laço é indicado pela subpalavra `y`. O que ocorre antes de `y` são os passos para chegar até o laço, que é a subpalavra `x`. O que vem depois é a cauda longa, que serve basicamente para terminar em um estado de aceitação, a subpalavra `w`. Logo, para usar o lema do bombeamento você precisa de uma palavra `x.y.z` tal que você possa bombear `y` quantas vezes quiser.

> Tem uma sacadas matemáticas (como `|x.y| <= p` para um `p` arbitrário dependente da linguagem e `|y| >= 1`) para garantir que o bombeamento é válido, porém não entrarei em maiores detalhes sobre ele, quis deixar uma ideia mais formal sobre o porquê do lema do bombeamento funcionar.
>
> Trabalhei o lema do bombeamento mais fortemente [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358113/64969)

### Como aplicá-lo

O lema do bombeamento é, como dito antes, uma condição sine qua non de linguagens regulares. Ou seja, se a linguagem não satisfizer o lema, então ela garantidamente não é regular. Portanto, esse lema deve ser usado para excluir linguagens de serem classificadas como regular. Ele não deve ser usado para classificar **positivamente** como regular.

Basicamente, você precisa escolher uma palavra que pertença a linguagem em questão e dividi-la em `x.y.z`. Como você não sabe quem é `p`, então escolha arbitrariamente uma palavra que, de algum modo, tenha essa característica já nela embarcada. Por exemplo, para provar que a linguagem sobre um alfabeto binário em que ambas as letras aparecem no mesmo número de vezes, escolhi a palavra `"0"^p . "1"^p`. Ou seja, não importa qual o valor de `p`, ele está contemplado. [Não vou repetir minha prova detalhada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358113/64969), mas qualquer `y` que você fizer conterá apenas `0`s, logo bombear mais vezes `y` vai gerar uma palavra com mais `0`s do que `1`s, logo a palavra bombeada não pertence à linguagem. Portanto, não é regular.

---

Anexo:

### Como provar que uma linguagem é regular?

Construa uma gramática regular que a reconheça. Essa é a prova direta. O lema do bombeamento vem pra dizer que, não importa o quanto você se esforce, será impossível criar uma gramática que reconheça **exatamente** a linguagem desejada.