# Diferença entre 'Linguagem regulares' para 'linguagem irregulares'

Tags: ciência-da-computação, teoria-da-computação, autômatos, linguagens-formais

Lendo uma questão sobre conceitos básicos de programação, deparo-me com a seguinte afirmação:

> Sejam A e B duas linguagens sobre o alfabeto binário, isto é, sobre o
>   alfabeto composto apenas por 0’s e 1’s. Seja A a linguagem na qual a
>   quantidade de 0’s e 1’s é igual. Seja B a linguagem onde nenhum 0
>   ocorre após um caractere 1, **apenas B é uma linguagem regular**.

Procurando aqui no site encontro a resposta: [O que é uma linguagem livre de contexto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180927/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-livre-de-contexto/210716#210716)
porém, mesmo assim, não ficou claro.

Minhas perguntas:

1. Quais são as principais diferença de uma linguagem regular para uma
   linguagem irregular? Na afirmação acima por que somente a linguagem B é regular?
2. Quais o principais exemplos das duas linguagens?

Comment: Se sabes inglês, [talvez isso te ajude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)

Comment: Vou dar uma olha sim, muito obrigado @LeonardoAlvesMachado

Comment: Basicamente as linguagens irregulares são as não regulares, ou seja não existe um forma especifica, aliais o Victor citou várias, e linguagem regular ali se referia são as que podem ser expressadas com expressões regulares (tag: [tag:regex]). Creio que se perdeu em algum momento no texto, que é bem extenso e informativo, mas realmente irregular não é "especifico". Aliais o termo irregular nem foi usado nas respostas, já que citam apenas regular e "outras". Não sou entendido do assunto, mas foi o que entendi em uma breve leitura.

Comment: hmm, então se puder usar expressões regulares basicamente será uma linguagem regular?está correto dizer isso? @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Creio que não, a propria regex dentro de uma linguagem de programação na verdade usa um interpretador, então algo como em PHP que use preg_match ou preg_replace, usa um sub-interpretador, ou seja expressão regular é a tal "linguagem regular", o PHP no caso só pega o resultado disto, como se fosse uma API interna, o mesmo é semelhante em outras linguagens.

Comment: Me ajudou a esclarecer, pois estava com esse conceito em mente, muito obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @LuizAugusto aguarde mais alguns comentários, pois admito que não é minha área esta parte de conceito de linguagens ("desligado" da programação), quero dizer, entendo sobre regex (devo dizer que amo xD) e diversas linguagens de programação,. mas os conceitos de definição para construir interpretadores e compiladores eu não domino, tem algumas pessoas no site que provavelmente vão confirmar ou explicar mais corretamente ;)

Comment: Mesmo não sendo sua 'área' já foi de grande ajuda, confesso que estou me apaixonando por regex também, embora dando os primeiros passos com o livro do Aurelio Marinho Jargas. Muito obrigado mesmo! @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Na classificação hieráquica de Chomsky as linguagen formais são classificadas como:

Tipo-0 - Recursiva / Recursivamente enumerável
Tipo-1 - Sensível ao contexto
Tipo-2 - Livre de contexto
Tipo-3 - Regular

Para cada tipo existe um reconhecedor, no caso da linguagem regular é um autômato finito.

Comment: Vou responder assim que der, mas, antes, só evitar um engano comum: as expressões regulares modernas (com retrovisores e tal) não representam _apenas_ as linguagens regulares, mas um superconjunto que engloba inclusive algumas linguagens sensíveis ao contexto (mais amplas que as livres de contexto já citadas na questão linkada).

Comment: @anonimo , a classe R é mais restrita que a classe RE. Eu tratei disso na questão sobre [busca em largura vs busca em profundidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/355343/64969)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem, acho que a resposta aqui talvez não agrade muito, mas é a correta: uma linguagem regular é aquela que pode ser gerada por uma gramática regular.

E, daí, o que seria uma gramática regular? Bem, seria uma gramática que possua *apenas* produções regulares. Bem, isso eu já expliquei [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313192/64969).

Reiterando o que foi falado na resposta acima: uma linguagem regular é intimamente relacionada a uma cadeia de Markov, onde para cada linguagem regular, há uma cadeia de Markov que a representa em forma e conteúdo.

---

Sobre gramática irregular... bem, estamos lidando aqui com um problema semântico. Estou tomando esse prefixo `i-` como sendo a negação do radical que se segue, no caso seria o `regular`. Nesse sentido, você teria as linguagens "não-regulares". O que significa qualquer linguagem que não possa ser descrita através de uma linguagem regular.

Porém, voltemos um passo. Qual a definição de número *irracional*? Seriam os números complementares aos racionais (isto é, os **não**-racionais)? Pois bem, a raiz quadrada de 2 e até mesmo o pi não são números racionais, daí posso chamá-los de irracionais, confere? Bem, até aí tranquilo, mas e quanto a raiz quarta de -1? Seria esse número *irracional*? Sabemos que não, esse número é um número *complexo*, e o número complexo não é nem racional *nem* irracional. Então, a definição de número irracional não pode ser simplesmente "aquele número que não é racional", ainda mais definindo os números reais como sendo a união dos racionais com os irracionais.

---

A linguagem não ser regular significa que [não tem forma específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/357489/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-linguagem-regulares-para-linguagem-irregulares#comment715107_357489)? Bem, na verdade verdade, não. Ela pode ter uma forma *extremamente específica*.

Por exemplo, a linguagem `D` formada por uma palavra de um alfabeto binário seguida dela mesma? Essa linguagem é definida mais ou menos assim: `D = { WW, para todo W em {a,b}* }`. Essa linguagem tem uma forma bem específica, porém é não regular (vou provar isso aqui depois de provar as linguagens `A` e `B`).

---

Sobre expressões regulares e linguagens regulares. No início, regex representavam **sim** linguagens regulares. Mas começaram a acrescentar coisas que não são regulares. Por exemplo, botaram a possibilidade de ter um retrovisor na consulta da regex. Em alguns motores de busca, eu posso reconhecer exatamente `D`:

```
([ab]*)\1
```

Também tem as opções de *look-ahead* e *negative look-ahead* para fazer um melhor caminho na máquina de estados e reconhecer/negar uma palavra. Porém, esse "olhar adiante" significa que não estamos mais lidando com uma cadeia de Markov. Ou seja, não regular. O *look-behind* significa a existência de memória, o que significa, novamente, não ser uma cadeia de Markov.

Você pode ver mais sobre regex vs linguagens regulares [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969), nos seus comentários e na resposta aceita.

---

O @anonimo [comentou sobre a Hierarquia de Chomsky](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/357489/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-linguagem-regulares-para-linguagem-irregulares#comment715188_357489). Porém, ele colocou no nível 0 tanto as linguagens recursivas quanto as linguagens recursivamente enumeráveis. Mas isso tem encrencas.

Um problema de decisão, na [ciência-da-computação](/questions/tagged/ci%c3%aancia-da-computa%c3%a7%c3%a3o), é equivalente a reconhecer se a entrada pertence à determinada linguagem, e quem define qual a linguagem válida é o problema. Por exemplo, o [Problema da Parada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/64969) é tão equivalente a verificar se, por acaso, uma palavra pertence a uma gramática irrestrita; esse é um problema da classe RE.

Porém, posso definir, em cima de uma linguagem qualquer, a sua linguagem complemento. Por exemplo, o Problema da Trava (que é a negação do Problema da Parada, que deve responder **sim** se o programa travar). Ele é o complemento do Problema da Parada. Ele é considerado um problema da classe co-RE. Ou seja, o Problema da Trava é equivalente a detectar se uma palavra pertence a uma linguagem co-RE.

Eu entro em mais detalhes dessas classe de complexidade na resposta sobre [busca em largura vs busca em profundidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/355343/64969).

---

Já respondi qual a diferença de uma linguagem regular para as outras. Todo o resto é consequência disso.

Uma dessas consequências é que as linguagens regulares obedecem ao lema do bombeamento. Podem existir linguagens não regulares que também obedeçam a esse lema, mas a não obediência implica necessariamente em ser não regular.

> [Leia mais nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313192/64969).
>
> [Leia mais (em inglês)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)

Então, como usar para provar que `A` não é regular?

> Considere o operador `.` como o operador de concatenação de palavras (recebe como operando duas palavras, retorna sua concatenação; `"abc" . "def" == "abcdef"`), e o operador `^` como o de repetição de palavras (recebe uma palavra e um número natural e retorna aquela palavra repetida o número vezes; "`"ba"."na"^3 == "ba"."nanana" == "bananana"`; `"ba"."na"^0 = "ba"`).

Precisamos, para tal, achar uma palavra no formato `x.y.z` pertencente a `A` e um número `p` tal que:

- `|y| >= 1`
- `|x.y| <= p`

De modo que, ao bombear `y` algumas vezes, a nova palavra `x.y^n.z` não pertença mais a `A`.

Então, peguemos a palavra formada por todos os `0`s a esquerda de todos os `1`s, e ambos com a mesma quantidade. Como `p` é arbitrário, então podemos pegar a palavra `"0"^p . "1"^p`. O que isso implica? Como `|x.y| <= p`,  não é possível que `y` possua o caracter `1`. Ou seja, `y = "0"^m, 1 <= m <= p`.

Bombeemos, então, `y` uma vez adicional. Ou seja, de `x.y.z` obteremos `x.y^2.z`, que é idêntico a `x.y.y.z`. Então, e a quantidade de `0`s nessa string? Bem, como `x.y` tem exatamente `p` `0`s, isso significa que `x.y.y.z` terá  `p + m` `0`s, porém a quantidade de `1`s não é alterada. Ou seja, se `x.y.y.z` pertencer a `A`, isso implica necessariamente em `p + m = p`; porém, sabemos que `0 < 1 <= m <= p`, o que significa que `p < 1 + p <= m + p <= 2*p`. Portanto, `p < p + m`. Logo, `x.y.y.z` não pertence a  `A`. Logo, `A` não é regular pois não atende ao lema do bombeamento.

---

Para provar que `B` é regular, basta escrever uma regex (regex pura, sem *look-arounds*, retrovisores ou outra coisa que não seja regular). Basicamente, nos resta as listas, listas negadas, agrupamentos, escolha (indicado normalmente pela barra-vertical `|`), quantificadores (opcional, estrela de Kleene, cruz de Kleene).

Em `B`, nenhum `0` pode ser precedido por `1`. Ou seja, se tiver a subpalavra `10`, já não pertence a `B`. Isso significa que palavras apenas com `0`s (palavras `z`) ou com `1`s (palavras `u`) são válidas. Além disso, posso fazer uma nova palavra com `z.u` sem nenhum problema.

Quem é o conjunto das palavras `z`? É `0*`. E o conjunto das palavras `u`? É `1*`. Portanto, `z.u` é a expressão regular `0*1*`.

Ou seja, `B` pode ser escrita como `0*|1*|0*1*`. Porém isso é trivialmente simplificado para `0*1*`. Como temos uma expressão regular, `B` é uma linguagem regular.

Sua gramática:

```
S -> '0'.S
S -> '0'
S ->
S -> '1'.U
U -> '1'.U
U -> '1'
```

Seu [autômato de estados finito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260864/64969) (com transação lambda, considerando que todos os estados são estados de aceitação):

```
 +---+       +---+
>| q0|>--+-->| q1|>--+
 +---+   |   +---+   |
   ^     |     ^     |
   |     |     |     |
   +- 0 -+     +- 1 -+
```

---

Vamos provar que `D` não é regular? Ela é a linguagem da palavra binária duplicada.

Escolhemos a palavra `"a"^p . "b"^p . "a"^p . "b"^p`. Ela é exatamente a palavra `"a"^p . "b"^p` duas vezes, portanto pertence a `D`. Isso significa que, necessariamente, `y` será composto puramente por `a`s. E daí? E daí que, bombear `y` significa obter a seguinte palavra:

```
"a"^n . ("a"^p . "b"^p)^2
```

Portanto, essa nova palavra não é uma duplicação de palavra. Logo, não pertence a `D`. Logo, `D` não é regular.

Comment: Jefferson, hoje estou viajando, mas amanha irei ler com máxima atenção sua resposta, mas desde já muito obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: Sensacional sua resposta!!! Consegui compreender muito bem quando você provou que A não é regular, mas B sim! Apenas deu um pequeno nó no cérebro quando você mencionou 'look-ahead e negative look-ahead ', mas procurei aqui no site e já consegui sanar as dúvidas!Muito obrigado mesmo @Jefferson