# Dúvida acerca da hierarquia de Chomsky

Tags: terminologia, ciência-da-computação, teoria-da-computação, linguagens-formais

A respeito dos 4 tipos de linguagens, tenho dúvida em compreender sobre a linguagem dependente do contexto ou sensível ao contexto.

Acho muito confusa a explicação que encontro pelos sites, gostaria que alguem me ajudasse a entender o que é uma **linguagem sensível ao contexto** e uma **linguagem irrestrita**.

Comment: Seria duplicata de [O que é uma linguagem livre de contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/5878)?

Comment: E também [Reduzir gramáticas na hierarquia de Chomsky](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313120/5878) | [Diferença entre 'Linguagem regulares' para 'linguagem irregulares'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/357489/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É relacionado e próximo, mas não é duplicata.

Answer (score 6):

### A hierarquia

A hierarquia de linguagens é essa:

[image: hierarquia]

As que Chomsky considerou à sua época, foram as linguagens regulares, livres de contexto, sensíveis ao contexto e irrestritas. No entanto, eu vou abordar todas elas, inclusive as outras três.

### Linguagens finitas

Uma linguagem finita é aquela que corresponde a um conjunto finito de cadeias de caracteres. Logo, uma linguagem não é finita se existir um conjunto infinito de cadeias de caracteres nessa linguagem.

### Linguagens regulares

Todas as linguagens finitas são regulares, mas nem todas as regulares são finitas.

Uma linguagem regular é aquela que pode ser expressa por uma expressão regular. Uma expressão regular consiste de sequências de caracteres que podem ter:

- (**a**) Repetições de determinadas subsequências em um indeterminado número de vezes e;
- (**b**) Escolhas entre duas ou mais subsequências.

A característica **b** existe nas linguagens finitas, e portanto é a **a** que aumenta o poder de reconhecimento das linguagens e permite que as linguagens regulares expressem um número infinito de cadeias de caracteres. Logo, uma expressão regular que não faça uso da característica **a** expressa uma linguagem finita.

Outras características frequentemente atribuídas às expressões regulares tal como repetição de subsequências uma ou mais vezes, repetição de subsequências um determinado número de vezes e subsequências que podem ou não aparecer, são todas características que advém de combinações das características **a** e **b** descritas acima.

## Linguagens livres de contexto

Todas as linguagens regulares são livres de contexto, mas nem todas as livres de contexto são regulares.

Uma linguagem livre de contexto é aquela que pode ser expressa por meio de uma gramática livre de contexto.

Uma gramática livre de contexto é um conjunto de regras de derivação recursivas aninhadas além daquilo que as linguagens regulares já são capazes de reconhecer. Cada regra, denominada de produção, é definida como a forma como um símbolo não-terminal pode ser expandido em uma sequência de símbolos terminais e não-terminais. A cadeia de caracteres a ser reconhecida ou gerada por uma gramática livre de contexto consiste apenas de símbolos terminais, sendo os símbolos não terminais usados apenas nas etapas intermediárias de geração ou reconhecimento da cadeia de caracteres.

Mesmo sem o uso de recursão nas regras, a possibilidade de expandir símbolos não-terminais em sequências de símbolos terminais e não-terminais é o suficiente para expressar as características **a** e **b** das linguagens regulares. Portanto, é a possibilidade de utilizar-se tal recursão que torna as linguagens livres de contexto mais expressivas do que as regulares. Uma gramática livre de contexto que não utilize dessa característica é equivalente a uma expressão regular.

Explico mais sobre as linguagens livres de contexto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/132).

## Linguagens sensíveis ao contexto

Todas as linguagens livres de contexto são sensíveis ao contexto, mas nem todas as sensíveis ao contexto são livres de contexto.

Uma linguagem sensível ao contexto é aquela que pode ser expressa por alguma gramática sensível ao contexto.

Uma gramática sensível ao contexto é um tanto similar a uma gramática livre de contexto, mas com uma grande diferença: As produções não necessariamente mapeiam apenas símbolos não-terminais para sequências de terminais e não-terminais. Elas podem mapear sequências de terminais e não-terminais para outras sequências de terminais e não-terminais, e essa característica as torna mais expressivas do que as gramáticas livres de contexto.

Um exemplo de gramática sensível ao contexto, [que peguei da Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples) e que reconhece a linguagem *{ a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>n</sup> : n ≥ 1 }* que não é livre de contexto é essa:

```
S → aBC
S → aSBC
CB → CZ
CZ → WZ
WZ → WC
WC → BC
aB → ab
bB → bb 
bC → bc
cC → cc
```

Observe que diferente do que ocorre numa gramática livre de contexto, a parte da esquerda das produções não se restringe a um símbolo não-terminal singular.

Gramáticas sensíveis ao contexto são muitas vezes confusas, difíceis de se entender e difíceis de se analisar. O principal motivo para isso é que elas definem regras que podem ser usadas para substituir qualquer coisa da entrada por qualquer outra coisa de qualquer jeito em qualquer ordem e em qualquer lugar. Efetivamente, elas são computacionalmente equivalentes às máquinas de Turing com memória limitada ao tamanho da entrada.

Assim sendo, usar essas regras de produções não é a única forma de especificar-se como funciona uma linguagem livre de contexto. Uma forma mais natural é a de defini-la como uma máquina de Turing determinística cuja fita na qual ela opera é limitada apenas ao tamanho da entrada. Sendo uma máquina de Turing, ela pode realizar qualquer tipo de operações de leitura, escrita e manipulações de símbolos nessa fita de entrada. Entretanto, uma vez que a sua fita é limitada e finita, ela ainda tem um poder computacional menor do que uma máquina de Turing com memória ilimitada.

Ao utilizar-se uma máquina de Turing determinística com um alfabeto muito maior do que o alfabeto de entrada, é possível simular-se uma máquina de Turing determinística que opere sobre uma fita de memória cujo tamanho máximo é o tamanho da entrada multiplicado por alguma constante arbitrária. Assim sendo, uma definição equivalente para uma linguagem sensível ao contexto é aquela que pode ser reconhecida por uma máquina de Turing determinística operando sobre uma fita cujo tamanho mantém uma relação linear com o tamanho da fita de entrada.

Um exemplo prático de uma linguagem sensível ao contexto que não é livre de contexto é a dada anteriormente, *{ a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>n</sup> : n ≥ 1 }*. Ou seja, a linguagem que corresponde a uma sequência de a's, seguida de uma sequência de b's e depois uma sequência de c's, onde o número de a's, b's e c's sejam iguais.

Outro exemplo de linguagem sensível ao contexto é o de verificar se pares de marcações de itálico (<i> - </i>), negrito (<b> - </b>) e sublinhado (<u> - </u>) abrem e fecham corretamente, mesmo que não estejam devidamente aninhados. Nessa linguagem, a sequência `ab<i>cd<b>ef</i>gh<u>ij</b>klm</u>no` é uma cadeia válida. Não há linguagem livre de contexto capaz de reconhecer isso.

Um outro exemplo simples de uma linguagem sensível ao contexto é aquela linguagem que consiste na sequência de dígitos entre 0 e 9 que expressam um número primo na base decimal. Novamente, não há linguagem livre de contexto capaz de reconhecer isso.

Mais um outro exemplo, e que abusa do poder computacional disponível, é o de determinar se uma sequência de símbolos representando variáveis, parênteses e os operadores lógicos E, OU e NÃO é ou não satisfatível. Esse é o [problema da satisfazibilidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) que é o problema NP-completo mais conhecido. A classe de linguagens sensíveis ao contexto é tão abrangente que engloba todos os problemas em NP.

## Linguagens recursivas

Todas as linguagens sensíveis ao contexto são recursivas, mas nem todas as recursivas são sensíveis ao contexto.

A definição de uma linguagem recursiva é simples: Tudo aquilo para o qual existe alguma máquina de Turing que a reconhece ou a rejeita em tempo finito.

É difícil pensar-se em uma linguagem recursiva que não seja sensível ao contexto. A maioria dos problemas computacionais com que nos deparamos no dia-a-dia são computacionalmente equivalentes ao reconhecimento de alguma linguagem sensível ao contexto.

Uma linguagem recursiva que não seja sensível ao contexto deve ser necessariamente impossível de ser reconhecida com o uso de uma quantidade de memória limitada ao tamanho da entrada multiplicada por qualquer constante, por mais arbitrariamente alta que ela seja. Isso já implica em uma complexidade computacional fora de NP e em problemas absolutamente intratáveis, embora ainda solucionáveis.

Exemplos de problema que são recursivos, mas não são sensíveis ao contexto:

- Determinar se duas expressões regulares são equivalentes.
- Verificar ou refutar a validade de sentenças de primeira ordem (que incluem variáveis, E, OU, NÃO, para todos (∀) e existe (∃)) com números reais, adição e comparação (mas sem multiplicação).
- Determinar se existe alguma estratégia perfeita para vencer um jogo de xadrez sendo desconsiderada alguma regra que force o empate após algum número arbitrário de movimentos sem captura para um tabuleiro de tamanho arbitrário.

Uma vez que as linguagens recursivas são aquelas que podem ser decididas em tempo finito, então as que não são recursivas são aquelas que não podem ser decididas em tempo finito para todos os casos. Em outras palavras, as linguagens que não são recursivas são indecidíveis.

## Linguagens recursivamente enumeráveis

Todas as linguagens recursivas são recursivamente enumeráveis, mas nem todas as recursivamente enumeráveis são recursivas.

Uma linguagem recursivamente enumerável (ou semi-decidível) é aquela que é aceita por alguma máquina de Turing em tempo finito, mas que pode demandar tempo infinito para ser rejeitada.

Para uma linguagem ser recursivamente enumerável sem que seja recursiva, é necessário que existam cadeias que não pertencem a linguagem, mas que seja impossível determinar-se isso em uma sequência finita de passos (afinal, ela deve ser necessariamente indecidível). Entretanto, cadeias que pertençam a linguagem em questão sempre podem ser decididas como tal em um número finito (mesmo que muito grande) de passos.

O exemplo clássico de uma linguagem recursivamente enumerável que não é recursiva é a do problema da parada. Dada uma descrição de uma máquina de Turing e uma cadeia de entrada, determinar se a máquina de Turing aceita ou não tal cadeia. Embora esse problema parece ser simples, na verdade é um problema muito cruel, pois simplesmente não existe algoritmo capaz de solucioná-lo em tempo finito para todas as possíveis entradas. Falo mais sobre esse problema [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/132).

## Linguagens irrestritas

Todas as linguagens recursivamente enumeráveis são irrestritas, mas nem todas as irrestritas são recursivamente enumeráveis.

A palavra irrestrita já diz o que a linguagem é: tudo e qualquer coisa. Esse é o conjunto que engloba todas as linguagens, inclusive as linguagens que não são recursivamente enumeráveis.

As linguagens que não são recursivamente enumeráveis são insolúveis. Elas contém cadeias de caracteres que são impossíveis de poderem ser determinadas como pertencentes a linguagem ou não.

De acordo com o [teorema de Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) decidir sobre qualquer propriedade semântica não-trivial de algum programa é um problema indecidível. Por propriedade trivial entenda-se aquelas que são válidas para todos os programas ou para nenhum programa (e portanto, as não-trivias são aquelas que são verdadeiras para uns e falsas para outros). Por propriedade semântica, entenda-se por propriedades sobre o comportamento do programa. Sendo indecidíveis, logo, esses problemas não são recursivos e muitos deles também não são recursivamente enumeráveis. Podemos utilizar isso para conceber algumas linguagens que não são recursivamente enumeráveis. Por exemplo:

- O conjunto de cadeias de caracteres que descrevem máquinas de Turing que decidam se as suas entradas são números primos.

Outro exemplo conhecido, que não depende do teorema de Rice é esse:

- O conjunto de cadeias de caracteres que representam pares de gramáticas livres de contexto que reconheçam a mesma linguagem.