# Como eu posso listar todos os e-mails inválidos?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

*Acabei encontrando algo do tipo devido a falta de validação que não tínhamos.*

```
teste@cliente
calteste5@calteste5
calteste6@calteste6
vava@ius
Pablo Fernandes
xxx
eduardostubbert
123456
1@1.com
xxx
a@a.a
xxx
a@a.com
x@x.com
bethania@
joao@bbb
daniel26@daniel26.c
caldemo5@caldemo5
teste@teste
xxxxx
usuario1
calteste4@calteste4
```

*Todos esses e-mails estão incorretos, então gostaria de saber os seguintes aspectos:*

- Existe um padrão(estrutura) que é adotado para se considerar um e-mail válido?
- Como listar todos os e-mails de uma coluna que fogem desse padrão? Ou
  seja, que são considerados inválidos?

*Obs:* Sei que mesmo que um e-mail não exista ele pode ser considerado válido. `Ex: xx@gmail.com`

Comment: Por que `teste@cliente` não seria válido?

Comment: Teste para cadastro , procure por "@" , "." não sei se dá para fazer algo além disto

Comment: @LINQ não sábia que era válido, só de conter o @ já é considerado um e-mail válido?

Comment: É que depende do escopo, @Marconi Por isso perguntei o motivo dele ser inválido. Num geral, é um formato completamente válido. Se queres um exemplo, aqui na rede local temos um servidor de e-mails sob o domínio `gaia`, meus colegas me mandam e-mail usando `linq@gaia`.

Comment: @Marconi , a RFC diz que os únicos endereços inválidos nesse cadastro são os que não tem `@` e o `bethania@`, que não tem a parte de domínio

Comment: @LINQ, tem uma "_recomendação_" da ICANN sobre domínios sem ponto; adicionei ao final da minha resposta

Comment: Por isso que eu falei que depende de escopo... Os domínios de e-mail daqui (locais) funcionam assim, independentemente se a ICANN ou o Jon Skeet falam o contrário. Se nosso sistema interno nos barrasse o cadastro destes endereços, ele seria inútil.

Comment: @LINQ eu não sabia que era rs! bom saber =D

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Vou ler direitinho sua resposta!

Comment: @LINQ SIm, verdade. ICANN não manda na sua empresa nem na sua casa. Eu pus essa observação por... bem, eu esqueci =) Eu acho que foi para focar no caso do Marconi, emails em produção/internet ampla

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## TL;DR

De modo geral, os emails mais padrões seguem a expressão regular `[^@]+@[^.@]+\.[^@]+`. Em `sql`, mais ou menos o seguinte pega a **um boa parte** dos casos positivos de email:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tabela_com_email t
WHERE
    t.email LIKE '%@%.%' AND
    t.email NOT LIKE '%@%@%'
```

## Endereço de email

Um endereço de email é um identificador composto por 3 partes:

1. `local-part`
2. `@`
3. `domain`

Com exceção do `@` que é uma constante, domínio e de parte local são regidos por regras próprias. Normalmente, qualquer endereço DNS pode sr usado na parte `domain`; inclusive, se for o caso de usar um endereço IP, você pode escrever `john.doe@[192.158.11.15]`, com colchetes para indicar IP literal (uma notação muito similar serve para IPv6). A parte local é bem mais chata de validar, veja a [sintaxe segundo a Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax).

### Exemplos bizarros de emails válidos

Copiado da Wikipedia:

> ```
> prettyandsimple@example.com
> ```

```
very.common@example.com  
disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com  
other.email-with-dash@example.com  
fully-qualified-domain@example.com.  
x@example.com
"very.unusual.@.unusual.com"@example.com  
"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com  
example-indeed@strange-example.com  
admin@mailserver1  
#!$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org  
"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org  
" "@example.org  
example@s.solutions  
user@localserver  
user@tt  
user@[IPv6:2001:DB8::1]
```

### Validadores na prática

Muitos validadores verificam a presença de um único `@`, forçando existir caracteres antes e depois. Outros validadores, que permitem menos spam que esse exemplo anterior que falei, levam em consideração que o domínio precisa ter pelo menos um ponto (`fulano@sicranet.org` ou `cicrano@silvatech.com.br`).

## Leitura mais aprofundada

Essas coisas de internet são regidas por RFCs. A RFC do endereço de email é a [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). A seção dedicada a esse assunto é a [seção 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1).

Do documento, temos a seguinte notação [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)-símile:

```
addr-spec       =   local-part "@" domain
local-part      =   dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part
domain          =   dot-atom / domain-literal / obs-domain
domain-literal  =   [CFWS] "[" *([FWS] dtext) [FWS] "]" [CFWS]
```

Sobre siglas:

- **RFC** - *request for comments*, requisição para comentários, documento de sugestão de padrões da internet da IETF
- **IETF** - *Internet Engineering Task Force*

## UPDATE - validando exemplo considerando apenas a RFC 5322

Emails que seriam válidos:

```
teste@cliente
calteste5@calteste5
calteste6@calteste6
vava@ius
1@1.com
a@a.a
a@a.com
x@x.com
joao@bbb
daniel26@daniel26.c
caldemo5@caldemo5
teste@teste
calteste4@calteste4
```

Emails que seriam inválidos (explicação depois do tilde ~):

```
Pablo Fernandes ~ não tem @, espaço não escapado
xxx ~ não tem @
eduardostubbert ~ não tem @
123456 ~ não tem @
xxx ~ não tem @
xxx ~ não tem @
bethania@ ~ não tem domínio
xxxxx ~ não tem @
usuario1 ~ não tem @
```

## Recomendação ICANN

A ICANN (Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers) <s>recomenda fortemente não usar</s> proíbe o uso de domínio sem ponto no endereço de email. [Fonte](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en)

## Construindo as expressões do começo da resposta

> Mais sobre regex consulte o [Guia de Consulta Rápida de Expressões Regulares](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/) do Aurélio Verde.

> Conforme vai surgindo um meta caracter de expressão regular, vou explicando em notas separadas como esta

Posso identificar os elementos válidos como uma linguagem. [Nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210716/64969) defino linguagem como um subconjunto das palavras geradas através da concatenação das letras denim conjunto.

De modo geral, todas as possibilidades de palavras sobre caracteres imprimíveis válidos é:

```
.*
```

> `.`: meta caracter de seleção que casa com qualquer caracter

> `*`: meta caracter quantificador que representa a [estrela de Kleene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star?wprov=sfsi1); zero ou mais repetições da expressão regular que precede esse operador

Um endereço de email precisa de uma `@` no meio da palavra:

```
.*@.*
```

Hmmm, o `*` é a estrela de Kleene, então ele validaria `@localhost` como válido. Preciso que exista pelo menos um caracter na parte de domínio e um na parte local:

```
.+@.+
```

> `+`: outro meta caracter quantificador, o mais de Kleene. É similar à estrela em tudo, mas exige a existência de pelo menos uma repetição; `R+` pode ser substituído sem diferença semântica por `RR*`. Alguns motores de expressão regular não reconhecem o `+`

Agora estou um pouco mais satisfeito, mas ainda reconhece `@@@` como email válido. A maioria dos serviços de email não permite esquemas mais estranhos, como aspas e escapes para evitar `@` no meio da parte local, também não permitem `@` na parte do domínio. De modo geral, simplesmente considerar a não existência do `@` da parte local e do domínio é bom o suficiente:

```
[^@]+@[^@]+
```

> `[^@]`: lista negada; aceita qualquer caracter que seja diferente dos caracteres entre a abertura `[^` e o fechamento `]`. No exemplo acima, só não aceita o `@`; pôde-se passar intervalos de caracteres, como `[^a-d]`, que nega todos os caracters de `a` até `d`

Ufa! Conseguimos achar muito bem. Mas ainda não segue a sugestão da ICANN, que exige a presença de um `.` no domínio:

```
[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+
```

> `\`: meta caracter de escape, também chamado de criptonita; remove totalmente qualquer interpretação possível de meta caracter do caracter seguinte; então `\.` aceita um ponto literal

### Construindo a expressão like

Comecemos da expressão regular:

```
 [^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+
```

De modo geral, algo que aceite uma quantidade arbitrária de caracteres é o `%`:

```
%@%.%
```

Isso garante a presença do `@` e de um `.` na parte do domínio. Porém isso não garante a presença de um único `@`. Para tal, basta que não seja parecido com o seguinte padrão:

```
%@%@%
```

Comment: Poderia explicar como funciona a expressão regular, no começo da pergunta @Jefferson? O link da [RFC 5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) está correto? Não conseguir achar a secção

Comment: @Marconi vou explicar melhor como cheguei na regex na resposta. Sobre a RFC, estou conseguindo abrir tranquilamente aqui. Título da seção: Addr-Spec Specification. Link direto para a seção: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1 (não tinha percebido antes que dava link direto)

Comment: Também vou editar a resposta e por o link direto onde cabe

Comment: Tranquilo @Jefferson, muito Obrigado! Grande resposta :)

Comment: @Marconi atualizado =] espera que tenha sanado as dúvidas