# Como selecionar este pedaço de texto em Regex

Tags: regex

Tenho o seguinte texto exemplo:

**1.1.1.1.1. Teste. Teste1.**

**1.1.1.1. Teste**

**1. Teste**

Gostaria de selecionar o **1.** de todos mas até o teste. Usei o seguinte regex: **([0-9]. )** o problema é que na primeira linha ele seleciona o **1.** no **Teste1.** e gostaria que selecionasse ate começar a primeira letra. Poderiam me ajudar com isso?

Agradeço desde já!

**EDIT 1:**

Selecionar tudo na frente do ultimo 1. também ajuda. Esses números são os níveis de uma árvore e gostaria de remover somente eles mantendo o resto do texto

Comment: Está usando alguma linguagem de programação ou apenas um editor de texto?

Comment: Estou usando Delphi, mas nesse caso é só para texto mesmo pelo Regex do delphi

Comment: @MatheusMachado a pergunta do rray é porque cada motor de regex tem suas peculiaridades

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara, percorre as linhas e aplica:

```
^\s*[0-9\.]*\s*
```

Essa regex remove o que você pretende... só que tem que ser rodada linha a linha, com um FOR ou um WHILE e dando um replace do valor encontrado por ''.

Caso prefira, pode usar a regex abaixo e substituir por uma quebra de linha (\n):

```
(^|\n)\s*[0-9\.]*\s*
```

Comment: Não entendi, poderia explicar melhor a solução?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era exatamente isso que queria **"^\s*[0-9\.]*\s*"**

Answer (score 4):

Se compreendi corretamente você deseja filtrar uma parte do conteúdo e quer substituí-la.

Assim mesmo que haja outras coisa o que você deseja sempre sera algo do tipo :

> 1.1.1.1.1. Teste.
>    1.1. Teste.
>    1. Teste.

Ainda comentou sobre arvore, neste caso podem haver outros índices como :

> 1.43.7.112. Teste.
>    26.0.177. Teste.

Mas você deseja remover os índices mantendo apenas o texto.

#### Resultado

```
pattern : /(\d+\.)+ (\w)/g
replace : $2
```

#### Explicação

- `(\d+\.)+` - Essa parte cuida dos índices, como é um grupo com `+`, ele vai repetido a possibilidade do grupo o máximo que consegue, sendo no mínimo 1.
- - Espaço literal (creio que apos o índice você tenha um espaçamento)
- `(\w)` - Grupo 2, limite da REGEX para saber quando o texto iniciou.

O *replace* substitui tudo que foi capturado.

- `$2` - substitui toda a sentença pelo carácter capturado no grupo 2.

Veja funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/6DEUGM/1).

Comment: Eu acho que o '.' no pattern deveria estar escapado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado correto, editado.

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo fazer expressões regulares sempre aos poucos, por partes. Olhe como eu construi uma [expressão para validar emails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/211339/64969).

Vamos lá, pegando o mais geral:

```
.*
```

Aqui casamos tudo, então vamos filtrar. É necessário pegar a partir do começo, então podemos colocar o âncora `^` logo:

```
^.*
```

Hmmm, você falou também que quer tudo até começar a primeira letra... então podemos casar tudo que não seja letras, que tal? Vamos usar a lista negada para isso:

```
^[^A-Za-z]*
```

Bem, vamos só nos certificar que vai até uma letra? Vamos usar a lista para isso, e também podemos agrupar para uma possível substituição de texto no futuro:

```
 ^([^A-Za-z]*)[A-Za-z]
```

Ok, agora temos o texto desejado no agrupamento reconhecido pelo retrovisor `\1` =D

> Mais sobre regex consulte o [Guia de Consulta Rápida de Expressões Regulares](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/) do Aurélio Verde.

Comment: Quem votou negativo poderia justificar o que eu respondi de errado?

Comment: Não sei pq votaram negativo, mas apesar de não ser o que eu queria isso me ajudou a pensar melhor na próxima vez que precisar usar regex, obrigado!

Comment: @MatheusMachado, fiquei feliz e triste pela sua resposta. Feliz por ter te ajudado a pensar melhor em regex, triste por não responder o que você queria. Vou tentar melhorar na próxima =)