# Dúvida em comando de entrada em programa em C++

Tags: c++, funções

Estou aprendendo funções agora em c++ e eis que fui tentar executar este programa. Acontece que quando eu executo ele simplesmente não deixa eu digitar o valor do `cin>>p;` ele simplesmente ignora o comando e passa para o próximo. Não sei o que está acontecendo. O programa é esse:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

float p,mai=0;
int i;
char nome,pesado;

void topo(){
    system("cls");
    cout<<"------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<" D E T E C T O R  DE  P E S A D O"<<endl;
    cout<<" Maior peso ate agora: "<<mai<<" kg"<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------"<<endl;
}

int main (void) {
    topo ();
    do{
        i+=1;
        cout<<"Digite o nome e depois o peso: "<<endl;
        cin>>nome;
        cout<<"\n";
        cin>>p; 
        if (p>mai){
            mai =p;
            pesado =nome;
        }
    topo();
    }while(i<=5);
    topo();
    cout<<"A pessoa mais pesada foi "<<pesado<<"com "<<mai<<" kg"<<endl;


}
```

Comment: Tem como você por a entrada que você está passando? Preciso dela verbatim, sem nem sobrar nem faltar um espaço ou enter

Comment: Olha como o Marconi pôs a entrada dos dados na dúvida dele nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211315/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado desse jeito ?

Comment: Você deixou seu código ilegível e não pôs entrada alguma

Comment: Quando vc fala de entrada, vc fala do que exatamente ? em relação ao código, era pra deixar do jeito que estava ? eu não entendi direito o que vc pediu pra fazer, desculpa, tô começando agr.

Comment: Quando falo entrada é no sentido daquilo que vai ser passado ao programa pela entrada padrão (normalmente o teclado). Por exemplo, olhe essa questão http://br.spoj.com/problems/COFRE/, ele tem o exemplo de entrada. Esse outro problema traz 3 exemplos de entrada: http://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/programacao/nivel2/2007f1p2_choc

Comment: e os comandos "cin>>" já não bastam pra entrada ?

Comment: Não perguntei como você fazia para receber a entrada, mas qual é a entrada. `cin >> nome;` indica como você recebeu programaticamente a entrada, mas eu não sei se você digitou `p` ou `Pedro` ou `Pedro Alonso` ou `umgrandenomedetestequeultrapassaacapacidadedeleituradaparadadastring`

Comment: Amigo, Antes do cout<<"\n" coloque fflush(stdin);

Comment: `nome` é do tipo `char` logo o seu nome apenas pode ser uma letra. E nesse sentido o programa está a funcionar bem. Se quiser ler um nome mesmo troque para o tipo `string` fazendo o include correspondente `#include <cstring>`

Comment: AndersonHenrique Fiz aqui e funcionou, na verdade nem sabia o que era o fflush(stdin), agora sei , valeu.
Isac Não tinha reparado nisso também, eu queria ler um nome mesmo, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Posso Colocar como Resposta então @PedroAfonso ?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que passar um ponteiro para caractere, não simplesmente um caracterer, então fica assim:

```
char *nome;
```