# Implementando expressao Regular no Java

Tags: java, string, regex

Preciso fazer um programa que leia um arquivo e consiga contar quantas classes e métodos tem.

A parte de leitura e separação por linha eu já fiz, preciso identificar classe e método.

Estou considerando que as classes e os métodos abram chaves na mesma linha que que começam e que não pulem a linha
Ex:
public class foo {
Não precisa ser um real contador de classes e métodos igual os validadores de código fazem.

Eu pensei em algo do tipo para classe:
Procurar em qualquer parte da linha a palavra **class** e verificar se termina com **{**
Ex:

```
public class Hello {
```

Expressão Regular:

```
["class"]{$
```

Método:
No final da linha verificar se tem na linha as palavras de **tipo de dado**(int, double, float, bool, char) e terminar com **){**.
Ex:
public **int** metodo(**){**
Expressão regular:

```
["int""double""float""bool""char"] )$
```

Eu só não sei como aplicar isso no java, se é só pegar os método de classe string de comparação e chamar:

```
String.compareTo(["class"]{$);
String.compareTo(["int""double""float""bool""char"] )$);
// Ou Asim
String.equals(["class"]{$);
String.equals(["int""double""float""bool""char"] )$);
```

Comment: Crie uma função, nessa função faça com que abra os arquivos de classe, após abri-los faça uma checagem com a regex que você deseja, armazene as ocorrências com uma lista, nesta lista coloque o path do arquivos de classe e a ocorrência da regex, armazene a lista como um arquivo txt, pronto, você acabou de implementar o programa que descreveu

Comment: Eu implementei sem expressões regulares depois eu edito a pergunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredite, isso que você quer fazer se chama `compilação`. Sim, você precisa compilar o código para fazer a contagem perfeita. Não, você não precisa gerar um bytecode com essa compilação. Não conheço outro alternativa a não ser montar a árvore de sintaxe abstrata que gere a informação perfeita; nesse caso, o melhor que você consegue com regex é uma estimativa. Para compilar Java, você precisa usar uma **linguagem livre de contexto**.

Ok, falei muita coisa mas nada prático ainda. Pois bem, [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/64969) traz uma gama de respostas sobre linguagens livres de contexto. A resposta do Victor está mais intuitiva, a minha está mais formal.

Mas por que Java é livre de contexto? Não tem nada em Java que eu possa fazer com uma linguagem regular?

> **Obs** uma linguagem regular é o conjunto de todas as strings formadas/reconhecidas por uma **expressão regular**

Basicamente porque o Java tem construções auto aninhadas. Como assim? Bem, veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: auto aninhamento]

Considere que `N` nesse caso é uma declaração de classe nomeada. Dentro dela, você pode declarar outra classe nomeada (tem um `N` aninhado em um outro `N`). A essa propriedade damos o nome de `auto aninhamento`. Se você tiver coisas`V` e `X` não vazios, você não consegue reduzir essa aninhamento para uma derivação regular.

> Se quiser um exemplo de código com 3 classes aninhadas uma na outra, veja [este snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1665800)

Leia as respostas [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180927/64969) antes de continuar lendo aqui. Pronto, terminou? Ok, vamos lá.

Para compilar Java, é muito salutar ter uma gramática que descreva a linguagem. Vou remover a questão referentes a comentários da compilação, ok? Essa simplificação não é absurdamente danosa, prossigamos.

Um código Java começa com declaração de pacote e de importações. Só depois disso eu declaro uma lista de classes (posso declarar mais de uma no mesmo arquivo, então tá válido). Se `J` for o não terminal inicial da nossa gramática para definir Java, temos isso aqui:

```
J -> P? Is C Cs
P -> "package" (RDNS | RDNS "\.\*") ";"
Is -> "" | I Is
I -> "import" "static"? RDNS ";"
Cs -> "" | C Cs
```

Parece alemão? Pois bem, não é exatamente alemão (alemão é sensível ao contexto, não dá para descrever com gramática livre de contexto).

Todos os símbolos que não estão entre aspas são símbolos não terminais; isso significa que eles vão ter produções que geram mais símbolos. O que está dentro de aspas são símbolos terminais; `";"` representa um ; literal.

Explicado isso, posso afirmar que a notação que eu usei é uma adaptação da [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form?wprov=sfsi1) expandida, onde eu coloco metacaracteres típicos de expressões regulares dentro das produções. Por exemplo, `"static"?` indica a presença opcional da palavra literal `static`, e `P?` indica que pode ocorrer a presença do não terminal `P` nessa parte da derivação de `J`.

Mais detalhes do que escrevi até agora:

1. `J` : não terminal que indica um programa válido dentro do **J**ava
2. `P` :  não terminal de declaração de **p**acote
3. `RDNS` : não terminal de ***R**eversed **DNS***; ainda não defini sua produção
4. `Is` : não terminal de **I**mport**s**, uma lista de importação
5. `I` : não terminal de **I**mport
6. `Cs` : não terminal de lista de **C**lasse**s**
7. `C`: não terminal de **C**lasse

E como é a produção que expressa uma classe?

```
C -> Ac? Nm Ex? Im? "{" Dsc "}"
```

Onde `Ac` é o nível de acesso, `Nm` é um nome qualquer válido, `Ex` é referente à herança, `Im` é sobre a lista de implementações de interface que essa classe implementa, `Dsc` é referente às declarações feitas dentro da classe.

Eu poderia passar a noite escrevendo as produções, mas não pretendo fazer isso. Queria só te deixar ciente de como escrever nessa notação. Feito isso, você monta a árvore de sintaxe, onde cada nó não folha é um símbolo não terminal e todos os filhos de um nó representa a derivação que o nó sofreu. Com a árvore de sintaxe, basta contar a quantidade de nós de classe `C` e os nós de métodos.

Depois de definir a gramática, você pode usar um compilador de compiladores (*compiler-compiler*) como o `yacc` e um reconhecedor léxico como o `yylex` para escrever seu compilador Java.

### Reconhecimento de classes nomeadas

Eu disse que reconhecer com expressões regulares é, na melhor das hipóteses, um valor aproximado. Vamos tentar? Uma classe começa com os modificadores de acesso (público? estático?), seguido da palavra reservada `class` e então o nome da classe:

```
(public|protected|private)? (static)? class [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Isso não leva em consideração esse texto estar dentro de strings nem de comentários.

### Reconhecimento de métodos

Eu disse que reconhecer com expressões regulares é, na melhor das hipóteses, um valor aproximado. Vamos tentar? Um método começa com os modificadores de acesso (público? estático?), seguido do seu retorno, seu nome, parênteses e lista de argumentos, fecha parênteses:

```
(public|protected|private)? (static)? [_a-zA-Z](\.?[_a-zA-Z0-9])* [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]* \(  ([_a-zA-Z](\.?[_a-zA-Z0-9])* [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]* (, [_a-zA-Z](\.?[_a-zA-Z0-9])* [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)*  )? \)
```

Note que isso não leva em consideração construtores.

> **para construtores**: construtores não podem ser estáticos, também não possuem retorno, de resto é idêntico a um método

```
(public|protected|private)? [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]* \(  ([_a-zA-Z](\.?[_a-zA-Z0-9])* [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]* (, [_a-zA-Z](\.?[_a-zA-Z0-9])* [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)*  )? \)
```